# php redirect after form success

Tags: php

Using php script to allow people to add their email to a mailing list. When it successfully writes the email to the .txt doc it displays a success message on a white page. I want it to redirect to a page I've designed to look like the rest of the site. I've read elsewhere that I need to use the header function, but I can't figure out where to put it since the preceding portion of my code contains outputs.

I think this is the relevant code:

```
// Write to file if email doesn't already exist
    if ($emailexists != "yes") {

        // Write to the list and give success message
        fwrite($fh, "$_POST[email]\n");
        $msg = "Your e-mail address $EmailFix was successfully added to the list!";
    }

    // Close the list
    fclose($fh);
}
```

Then this:

```
// Show success message if there was one and end script, and no errors were encountered
} elseif (isset($msg)) {
echo "<b>" . $msg . "</b>\n";
echo "</body>\n";
echo "</html>\n";
exit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
header("Location: http://...");
```

or

```
header("Location: filename.php");
```

**Make sure there's no HTML output before calling the header function!**

Comment: You can also drop in a Javascript or Meta redirect if you aren't confident dealing with output buffering.

Comment: Should add exit(); after that too.

Comment: This is a better choice than a javascript redirect etc.

Comment: Strongly recommend this method as it will work without the need for JavaScript. Also as AR said make sure to put an exit(); afterwards to make sure no code after it is executed.

Comment: Ok, so changed it to this:     
            fwrite($fh, "$_POST[email]\n");
            header('Location: http://www.marthascanlan.com/new/thanks.php');
   exit();
and got an error message saying cannot modify header information. How do I identify HTML output?

Comment: Thanks Dnns, this is probably a stupid question, but how do I identify HTML output?

Comment: That error probably means there's already some HTML output. Try checking if there's nog "space" on the top of your document. Another thing you can do is putting your "<?php ?>" on top of your document (if thats possible).

Comment: Thanks again Dnns, I put the php on the top of my document and everything is working great!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this message to still show and THEN redirect them somewhere else?  Or do you want to discard this message all together and direct them to a different page that will have a similar message?

You could show that page as is, and include another echo to trigger a redirect:

```
echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"REFRESH\" CONTENT=\"2;URL=/someotherpage.php\">";
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't want the user to see that message at all just get redirected to a page with a similar message...

Answer (score 0):

If your previous code contains code than you can use javascript redirection:

```
window.location = "YOUR_URL_HERE";
```

You should norify the user the user that s/he will be redirected.

Comment: Agreed regarding notification of the user.  Set the redirect on a timer -- three to seven seconds is usually ideal, and keeps the user from getting disoriented.